# Sharepoint 2010. Как после заполнения формы для одного списка автоматически открыть форму для другого списка

Tags: списки, формы, sharepoint, автоматизация

Я создал два списка Sharepoint 2010 - один "проверка" (содержит общие сведения о проверке и количество нарушений), другой "нарушения" (содержит подробную информацию о нарушении).

Как сделать так, чтобы после заполнения формы для первого списка ("проверка") автоматически открывалась форма для "нарушения" при этом  записи в списке "нарушения" должны быть связаны с определенной проверкой (к примеру по полю "ИД")?

Так же необходимо как то сделать так, чтобы при необходимости внести несколько нарушений за одну проверку это тоже можно было бы легко выполнить.

Схематически заполненные записи выглядит примерно так:

```
Список "Проверка":
     "ИД: 1",...,"нарушения:2";
     "ИД: 2",...,"нарушения:1";
 Список  "Нарушения":
     "ИД: 1"...,"ИД_Проверки: 1";
     "ИД: 2"...,"ИД_Проверки: 1";
     "ИД: 3"...,"ИД_Проверки: 2";
```

Answer (score 1):

> *Как сделать так, чтобы после заполнения формы для первого списка ("проверка") автоматически открывалась форма для "нарушения"*

Как вариант, URL для перенаправления на форму создания "нарушения" после создания "проверки" можно задать через параметр Source.

> *при этом записи в списке "нарушения" должны быть связаны с определенной проверкой (к примеру по полю "ИД")?*

На форме создания "проверки" после загрузки страницы, javascript'ом узнать последний ID в списке нарушения и подставить его в лукап поле.

Этот вариант решения быстрый (но не самый лучший) и использует стандартные формы создания элементов списков (NewForm.aspx).

Можно создать свои формы, этот вариант решения позволит решить

> *необходимо как то сделать так, чтобы при необходимости внести несколько нарушений за одну проверку это тоже можно было бы легко выполнить.*